# ROOT file for building a heap image in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I use Isabelle, and I have a theory that is processed for long interactively so I wanted to build a heap image. Therefore I created a ROOT file:

```
$ cat ROOT 
session MYTHEORY = HOL +
  description "The definition of my theory"
  theories [document = false]
    MyTheory
```

upon which I built an image:

```
$ isabelle build -c -D .
Cleaned MYTHEORY
Running MYTHEORY ...
Finished MYTHEORY (0:00:01 elapsed time)
0:00:03 elapsed time
```

and then I tried to use that heap image, but then I got an error message:

```
$ isabelle jedit -l MYTHEORY
16:51:07 [AWT-EventQueue-0] [error] ErrorListDialog$ErrorEntry: *** Undefined session(s): "MYTHEORY"
```

What did I wrong, what did I not understand?

Comment: I'm able to reproduce in an old version of Isabelle, I'll try the development one (I'm actually unable to re-build some old project of mine; once I find out I'll post an answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Isabelle/jEdit is not aware of this session that are proving. You can indicate that by feeding the directory where the session is stored:

```bash
$ isabelle jedit -d . -l MYTHEORY
```

assuming that the session lies (as it seems) in the present directory. (**Note**. This does not requires prior building.)

I'm trying to recall how did manage to avoid the `-d .` option, but in the meantime this might work for you.

**EDIT**. In order to make Isabelle aware of your session, you should add it as a component:

```bash
$ isabelle components -u /absolute/path/to/Session/
```

After that, you will be able to simply run `isabelle jedit -l MYTHEORY`.