# Referring to a session properly in another ROOT file in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

This is a follow-up to [ROOT file for building a heap image in Isabelle](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/2741/root-file-for-building-a-heap-image-in-isabelle) .

I have a main directory where my main theory resides. I have a ROOT file there:

```
session MAINSESSION = HOL +
  theories [document = false]
    MainTheory
```

and an app subdirectory from there with another ROOT file:

```
session APPLICATION = HOL + 
  sessions
     MAINSESSION
  directories 
     ".."
  theories [document = false]
     Application
```

Now, running

```
app$ isabelle build -v -D .
```

I get

```
*** Bad imports session "MAINSESSION" for "APPLICATION" (line 1 of "app/ROOT")
```

What is the problem here and how can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to proceed seems to be declaring both your main session and the application in the same ROOT file at the main directory:

```
session MAINSESSION = HOL +
  theories [document = false]
    MainTheory

session APPLICATION in app = HOL + 
  sessions
     MAINSESSION
  theories [document = false]
     Application
```

The `directories` option does not seem to apply here, since it refers to  “additional directories for import of theory files **via theories** within ROOT **or imports** within a theory”, as per the [system manual](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2023/doc/system.pdf).

In general, sessions sharing directories are [apparently frowned upon](https://lists.cam.ac.uk/sympa/arc/cl-isabelle-users/2020-04/msg00109.html).